# Installing TCPFLOW on Pi V2 running Jessie from the GIT site

Tags: git, raspberry-pi2, debian-jessie

I've done this before but yesterday I could not get it to work! Running Jessie on a Raspberry Pi v2.

Working from the GIT site (https://github.com/simsong/tcpflow/) I'm trying to install the latest version of TCPFLOW. I have done the

> apt-get update

and then the

> apt-get upgrade

so I'm sure the OS is up-to-date.

There seem to be some comments in the git site which I have not noticed before:

> To compile for Linux 
>   Be sure you have the necessary precursors. There are files in the root
>   directory that will do this for you, depending on your host operating
>   system:
>
> CONFIGURE_ARCH_17_8.sh 
>   CONFIGURE_FEDORA_18.sh
>   CONFIGURE_FEDORA_26.sh
>   CONFIGURE_UBUNTU_16_04.sh

**I'm not sure if I should be running one of these scripts on my Raspberry Pi V2 running Jessie?**

However, following my older notes and the other docs on the git site, when I run the

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/simsong/tcpflow.git
```

command it seems to run ok with no error messages. However when I try to run the rest of the commands:

```
cd tcpflow
bash bootstrap.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

it fails on the

> bash bootstrap.sh

line saying that bootstrap.sh does not exist!

If I list the new tcpflow directory, sure enough there is no bootstrap.sh file.

There is a

> bootstrap.bash

which does seem to run but gave errors for missing modules. I ran this to correct that problem:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get install git gcc g++ automake autoconf libpcap-dev libboost-dev libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libcairo2-dev
```

Rerunning

> bash bootstrap.bash

now gave these messages:

> autom4te: cannot create autom4te.cache: No such file or directory
>   autoheader: '/usr/bin/autom4te' failed with exit status: 1 autom4te:
>   cannot create autom4te.cache: No such file or directory aclocal:
>   error: echo failed with exit status: 1 autom4te: cannot create
>   autom4te.cache: No such file or directory autom4te: cannot create
>   autom4te.cache: No such file or directory automake: error: autoconf
>   failed with exit status: 1 be sure to run ./configure

Now when I try to run

> ./configure

I get the command not found or file on found error.

This whole process is totally different from the previous times I've run it and does not follow my notes nor the docs on the GIT site. Help, please
....RDK

Answer (score 0):

OK, these issues have been resolved.  The issue around the ***configure.sh*** vs ***configure.bash*** has been fixed by the TCPFLOW developers.  The file has been renamed to match the documentation.

The "**cannot create**" errors after I ran the "***bash configure.bash***" file the second time were permission errors due to my having run the initial git cloning as root but the subsequent commands as my normal user.

Now the installation has completed without any errors.....RDK